# AAC->PCM変換時のサンプリングレート変換

Tags: android

AACのストリーミングデータをMediaCodecを利用してPCMに変換しているのですが、このときダウンサンプリングしたPCMを取得することは出来ないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

少なくともAndroid 7.1(API Level 25)現在では、MediaCodecに音声サンプリングレート変換機能は存在しません。

自前でサンプリングレート変換を記述する必要があります。もしくは https://github.com/hutm/JSSRC のようなJava製ライブラリ(GPLv2)を検討してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはりそうですよね。。。助かりました。